# CSS as neexed width in one line

Tags: html, css

I want to crate a view on my page:

[image]

where:

1) the red item is the `main container` and has the `width:100%`

2) the `green`, `blue` and `white` elements are in the one container which has the width as needed and is on the center of the `main container`

3) the `green` elements have the fix `width:50px`

4) the `blue` elements have the width as needed (depends on the text length inside but the text has to be the same so both elements have the same width)

5) the `white` element has fix `width:100px`

I tried something like:

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100%;background:red">
    <div style="height:100px;display:inline-block;margin:auto">
        <div style="height:100px;width:50px;background:green;float:left"></div>
        <div style="height:100px;display:inline-block;background:blue;float:left">MyText</div>
        <div style="height:100px;width:100px;background:white"></div>
        <div style="height:100px;display:inline-block;background:blue;float:left">MyText</div>
        <div style="height:100px;width:50px;background:green;float:left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the result is totally wrong...
[image]

How is it possible to get this effect?

Comment: use float right in the inner blocks instead of float left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this. You simply need to use `inline-block` elements without float:

```css
.main {
  background:red;
  font-size:0;
  text-align:center;
  height:100px;
}
.main > div {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:initial;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.blue {
  background:blue;
}
.green {
  width:60px;
  background:green;
}
.white {
  width:100px;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue">text inside</div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="blue">text inside</div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

And in case the geen and white block are simply used for the visual effect you can easily replace them with some background and box-shadow:

```css
.main {
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.main > div {
  background:#fff;
  font-size:0;
}
.main div {
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.blue {
  background:blue;
  font-size:initial;
}
.main  .blue:first-child {
  margin-right:50px;
  box-shadow:-25px 0 0 25px green;
}
.main  .blue:last-child {
  margin-left:50px;
  box-shadow:25px 0 0 25px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
  <div class="blue">text</div>
  <div class="blue">text inside</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want the white part to be the *dead* center you can try this:

```css
.main {
  height:100px;
  font-size:0;
}
.main > div {
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  width:calc(50% - 50px);
  height:100%;
  font-size:initial;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.main > div .blue {
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:blue;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50px green;
}

.main  > div:first-child {
  text-align:right;
  margin-right:50px;
}
.main  > div:last-child {
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="blue">text</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="blue">text very long inside</div>
  </div>
</div>
```